# Best way to code on one system, test on another (GIT, Python, Raspberry Pi)?

Tags: python, git, raspberry-pi

My apologies if this has been answered somewhere.  I looked and did not find an answer to this rather specific question.

My environment:
**PC:** Windows 10 Home, Dual Monitors, Git Bash, PyCharm, static IP assigned
**Raspberry Pi**: GPS Module (NMEA 0183 interface connected via USB
Developing a data logger utilizing Python with flask and serial modules

Since my PC is much easier to develop on, I have been updating the code there but I need to actually test it on the Raspberry Pi because it has the GPS module and is my target environment.  I was pushing the changes via GIT to BitBucket.  I would then pull the changes back down to my R Pi - this was working OK but it required me to commit and push after each update.  I was trying eliminate a step using my local network.

I added a remote name "Pi3" to my project on the PC but when I tried to push the updates to my Pi I got a message saying "[remote rejected] (branch is currently checked out).  I could checkout the master, push the updates and then re-checkout my development branch but by the time I do this I might as well hop through BitBucket.

I then tried doing a pull or fetch from my Pi 3 but since I do not have an sshd (SSH server) running on my PC, it naturally failed. A quick look at setting up a SSH Server on Windows 10 looks like a huge pain.  I am willing to endure that pain for long term gain but I am unsure if this would get me there even after I set it up.

I guess another solution is to script using scp to copy the files that I want but that requires maintenance as the project grows or I work on a different project. I can't be the only one that codes on one system and tests on another.

Any suggestions or feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Assuming the machines are on the same network, you could use a remote editor like VS Code's Remote SSH client to run the editor on your desktop, but run the code remotely.

Comment: Searching online I see mention of `GitPi` and others that might help with pushing to your Pi.  You might want to back that up daily because both your hw and sw are in the same egg basket.

Comment: Whats wrong with developing on the Pi via Remote Desktop?

Comment: @AnonCoward Interesting thought that I had not considered.  It appears that PyCharm also has the feature you suggested but it like it is only available in the 'Professional' version.  Now to see how much it is and if I can justify the cost.  I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: @couka From what I understand PyCharm can be run but it is quite sluggish. Also, it only supports a single monitor (R Pi 3B+) via HDMI.  VNC only displays across one screen of screen real estate as well.  Ultimately the answer becomes that I am spoiled by PyCharm with a dual monitor.  :-)

Comment: another option similar to @couka's is X11 forwarding. eg pi has PyCharm and ssh server, desktop has putty (see https://superuser.com/questions/119792/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty). the caveat is you would need X11 on windows, which is possible but I can't comment on how well it runs or if it supports dual monitors like you want

Comment: Another option to consider:  Setting up a SMB or NFS share on your desktop that the Pi runs files from.  Running code over a network share isn't perfect, but perhaps it'll ease your development issues.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your workflow is based around git and new commits should be made available on the remote machine (Pi). You might want to define a post-commit or [post-receive](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive) hook to copy your latest code over to the Pi, preferably via `rsync`.

See more about git hooks [here](https://githooks.com/).

Another option is to define your remote git as `bare` clone (see [here](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)), so you can just push to the remote git without conflicting checked-out branches in the way.